# Force screen orientation with config changes

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

I am using a android project as a lib whose Activity's manifest says:

```
<activity
        android:name="pay.CardActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

In CardActivity onOrientationChanged() is overrriden and there is rotation logic written in it.

I want to lock the CardActivity to portrait always from my main project. I tried doing

```
<activity
    android:name="pay.CardActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

But that did not lock the orientation. Is there a way to do this? CardActivity is final, so I cannot extend and override its onOrientationChanged() method.

Comment: Adding attribute android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the manifest.xml should alone work.Nothing extra

Comment: Use both android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Answer (score 0):

```
   <activity
        android:name="my.app.somename.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
    </activity>
```

and per activity (screen)

```
     <activity
        android:name="my.app.somename.activities.ActivityChooseSomeMethod"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this..**

```
<activity
    android:name="pay.CardActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

just below line in your manifiest file which will set your activity's orientation.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```